# Extract text only except the content of script tag from html with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I have html like this

```
<span class="age">
    Ages 15
    <span class="loc" id="loc_loads1">
     </span>
     <script>
        getCurrentLocationVal("loc_loads1",29.45218856,59.38139268,1);
     </script>
</span>
```

I am trying to extract `Age 15` using `BeautifulSoup`

So i written python code as follows

**code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib3

URL = 'html file'

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

page = http.request('GET', URL)

soup = bs(page.data, 'html.parser')
age = soup.find("span", {"class": "age"})

print(age.text)
```

**output:**

```
Age 15 getCurrentLocationVal("loc_loads1",29.45218856,59.38139268,1);
```

I want only `Age 15` not the function inside `script` tag. Is there any way to get only  text: `Age 15`? or any way to exclude the content of `script` tag?

> PS: there are too many script tags and different URLS. I don't prefer
>   replace text from the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.find(text=True)`

**EX:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<span class="age">
    Ages 15
    <span class="loc" id="loc_loads1">
     </span>
     <script>
        getCurrentLocationVal("loc_loads1",29.45218856,59.38139268,1);
     </script>
</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("span", {"class": "age"}).find(text=True).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Ages 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but for future reference, you can also use [decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to remove all `script` elements from the `html`, i.e.:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")                  
# remove script and style elements                         
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):                   
    script.decompose()                                     
print(soup.find("span", {"class": "age"}).text.strip())    
# Ages 15
```

Comment: thanks for the additional info. i will keep that in mind